# Flutter app crashes when configured to use Mac Camera

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-camera

Im trying to add a camera and take a picture option in a flutter app. Using an android emulator when I load the app, it instantly crashes and gives out some errors.
I used the camera.dart library and heres what my build Widget build looks like

```
  @override


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Take a picture')),
      // You must wait until the controller is initialized before displaying the
      // camera preview. Use a FutureBuilder to display a loading spinner until the
      // controller has finished initializing.
      body: FutureBuilder<void>(
        future: _initializeControllerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            // If the Future is complete, display the preview.
            return CameraPreview(_controller);
          } else {
            // Otherwise, display a loading indicator.
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        // Provide an onPressed callback.
        onPressed: () async {
          // Take the Picture in a try / catch block. If anything goes wrong,
          // catch the error.
          try {
            // Ensure that the camera is initialized.
            await _initializeControllerFuture;

            // Attempt to take a picture and get the file `image`
            // where it was saved.
            final image = await _controller.takePicture();

            if (!context.mounted) return;

            // If the picture was taken, display it on a new screen.
            await Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => DisplayPictureScreen(
                  // Pass the automatically generated path to
                  // the DisplayPictureScreen widget.
                  imagePath: image.path,
                ),
              ),
            );
          } catch (e) {
            // If an error occurs, log the error to the console.
            print(e);
          }
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is how the camera is initialised

```
  void initState() {
super.initState();
// To display the current output from the Camera,
// create a CameraController.
_controller = CameraController(
  // Get a specific camera from the list of available cameras.
  widget.camera,
  // Define the resolution to use.
  ResolutionPreset.medium,
);

// Next, initialize the controller. This returns a Future.
_initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
```

}

I have set the back camera to webcam0 in avd settings and also checked the available cameras which returns my camera on my mac. The app works if its a emulated camera but crashes the moment its a real camera. Theres a few issues but I think they can be solved by changing one or two things which are to do with flutter finding the camera itself.
What do I need to change about my camera settings to get the app to use the camera properly.
Here is the error log

```
    [ERR] The Android emulator exited with code -4 after startup
[ERR] Android emulator stderr:
[ERR] WARNING | cannot add library /Users/naeemujeeb/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-aarch64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib: failed
[ERR] WARNING | *** No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.***
[ERR] [11764:103316:20240322,183036.876846:WARNING crash_report_exception_handler.cc:235] UniversalExceptionRaise: (os/kern) failure (5)
[ERR] Address these issues and try again.
[ERR] Error 1 retrieving device properties for sdk gphone64 arm64:
[ERR] adb: device 'emulator-5554' not found

[ERR] Error 1 retrieving device properties for sdk gphone64 arm64:
[ERR] adb: device 'emulator-5554' not found

[ERR] The Android emulator exited with code -4 after startup
[ERR] Android emulator stderr:
[ERR] WARNING | cannot add library /Users/naeemujeeb/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-aarch64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib: failed
[ERR] WARNING | *** No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.***
[ERR] [12966:113491:20240322,183623.961294:ERROR directory_reader_posix.cc:42] opendir /tmp/android-naeemujeeb/emu-crash.db/attachments/0727ce45-6131-437c-91c6-eb39d264bc86: No such file or directory (2)
[ERR] [12966:113490:20240322,183624.089613:WARNING crash_report_exception_handler.cc:235] UniversalExceptionRaise: (os/kern) failure (5)
[ERR] Address these issues and try again.
```